# Definition for a sentence used in thesis/dissertation cover pages

Tags: british-english

I was looking at some cover pages and see that most of them use the following sentence;

> A THESIS SUBMITTED IN PARTIAL FULFILLMENT OF THE REQUIREMENTS FOR THE
>   DEGREE OF....

What does it really mean? "partial fulfillment" i am not sure if to use that in my cover page

Comment: Use it because the thesis is only one requirement. There are others. You have to take certain courses, you have to earn a certain GPA, you have to pass a qualifying exam, and you have to have to successfully defend your thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Partial fulfilment" means exactly that: it doesn't fulfil all the requirements for the degree. Other requirements could be a written examination (or a series of them); or a *viva voce* examination; or something else.

Your educational establishment should be able to give you guidance in your specific case.

Comment: Is it referring to the other modules undertaking in the year 1 and 2 ? for instance

Comment: My thesis is 85% and my presentation is 15%, hence thats why it refers to it as partial?

Comment: It isn't that exact. There are number of requirements and you have to fulfil all of them.